# Linq Object reference not set to an instance of an object - inner collection null

Tags: c#, linq

I've got an issue with a `linq` query that's causing an exception.  I know why the exception is happening, but I'm not sure what the best way to rewrite the query is.  I'd like to keep it in `linq` if at all possible, but am not opposed to using loops and null object detection if that's the better approach.

Here's my query - the problem is that `AnalysisResults` is sometimes null (not simply an empty instantiated collection).  That said, it's also possible for the predecessor collections to be null, so I'd prefer an approach that can be applied to all of the collections.

```
benchmarks = (from p in cacheData.SiteSources
                              from q in p.SiteGroup.SiteGroupSites
                              from r in q.Site.AnalysisResults
                              where r.BufferTypeId == bufferTypeId &&
                              r.BufferValue == bufferValue
                              select r).ToList();
```

Is there a succinct way to work around the null `AnalysisResults`?

Comment: Change your objects to not return null but an actual empty result. This is exactly why you shouldn't return null when a collection is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, filtering those cases where is `null` using a `Where`:

```
benchmarks = (from p in cacheData.SiteSources
              from q in p.SiteGroup.SiteGroupSites
              where q.Site.AnalysisResults!=null
              from r in q.Site.AnalysisResults
              where r.BufferTypeId == bufferTypeId && r.BufferValue == bufferValue
              select r).ToList();
```

Comment: Mixing both kinds of Linq syntax is a bit nasty though.

Comment: Right, let me fix it

Comment: Cool, that works - I've never used the `where` clause anywhere but the bottom before, nice to see how that works in the this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some `where` clauses to check for null

```
benchmarks = (from p in cacheData.SiteSources
                          where p.SiteGroup.SiteGroupSites != null
                          from q in p.SiteGroup.SiteGroupSites
                          where q.Site.AnalysisResults != null
                          from r in q.Site.AnalysisResults
                          where r.BufferTypeId == bufferTypeId &&
                          r.BufferValue == bufferValue
                          select r).ToList();
```